# Clarification about the result of a multivariable limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I studied $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,0)}\frac{\left(x-2\right)^{2}-y^{2}}{x-2}$ and I found it doesn't exist because in polar coordinates there is no uniformity respect to the angles. I represented it on geogebra 3d and i saw that once you fix a $\epsilon >0$ the points of the domain for which the function is evalueted between $0+\epsilon$ and $0-\epsilon$ (i will denote it A) have equation of a two circles having the centres and the tangent point on the x axes. Examples: $\epsilon =5$ , set A : $(x-9/2)²+y²=25/4$ or $(x+1/2)²+y²=25/4$. Personally i don't know any norm which has this shape. Moreover any norm i know doesn't generate a ball centered in (2,0,0) completely contained in A. Does it exist? The set of the open sets generated by any topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ should be the same, in the sense that if i use a topology associated to a norm that generates a square or a circle is the same thing as i always find a square in a circle and viceversa. Is the result of the limit linked to this in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<\delta<1 $ and let $\lvert \lvert (x,y) \rvert \rvert <\delta $; then  $\lvert \frac{(x-2)^{2}-y^{2}}{x-2}-(-2) \rvert=\lvert\frac{(x-2)x-y^{2}}{x-2} \rvert < \frac{2\delta +\delta^{2}}{2-\delta}<3 \delta$, so given $\epsilon$ ;it suffices to choose $\delta < min \{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$.this proves that the limit is -2.
Regarding the norm used,we know that all norms are equivalent for a finite dimensional normed space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$,and being continuous wrt to norm is equivalent to being continuous wrt to an equivalnet norm, So we can fix the norm to be $\lvert \lvert (x,y) \rvert \rvert =\lvert x  \rvert + \lvert y \rvert  $ .Moreover, one can prove that there is a unique Hausdorff topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that the addition and scalar multplication are continous

Comment: sorry i meant limit for (2,0) @belkacem abderrahmane